# LINQ query optimization: specifically, does position of let clauses matter?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm interested in the compilation and optimization LINQ expressions and whether or not I need to carefull consider the order of let and where clauses in my expression.

Here is example:

```
var query = 
    from record in Database.Table
    let recordName = record.GetName()
    let notUsed = UselessData()
    let stuff = DoSomethingIntensiveWith(record)
    where recordName == "foobar"
    select stuff;

foreach (string item in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("item => '{0}'", item);
}
```

Questions/assumptions:

- `record.GetName()` must be resolved in order to execute the `where`
  clause.
- `notUsed` is never used in the expression, so will `UselessData()` get called
  at all?
- `stuff` is only needed if `recordName` equals "foobar". Will
  `DoSomethingIntensiveWith()` be executed for every record or just records
  where `recordName` equals "foobar"?

If I want to ensure `DoSomethingIntensiveWith()` is only called when 
`recordName` equals "foobar", do I need to position the `let` caluse after the
`where` clause, as follows:

```
var query = 
    from record in Database.Table
    let recordName = record.GetName()
    let notUsed = UselessData()
    where recordName == "foobar"
    let stuff = DoSomethingIntensiveWith(record)
    select stuff;

foreach (string item in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("item => '{0}'", item);
}
```

In the meantime, I'm going to play with some real code and the debugger. I'll
report back what I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is LINQ-to-Objects, then: yes, you do. The standard `Enumerable.*` implementation is very direct in terms of applying things in order. You don't need all the `let` clauses necessarily, but things are still done in order, and that order is respected. If it is LINQ-to-anything-else, then all bets are off.

This is easy to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Foo
{
    public Foo(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public string Expensive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
        return Value;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        var foos = new[] {
            new Foo("abc"),
            new Foo("def")};
        Console.WriteLine("query1:");
        var query1 = (from obj in foos
                      let val = obj.Value
                      where val.StartsWith("a")
                      let result = obj.Expensive()
                      select result).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("query2:");
        var query2 = (from obj in foos
                      let val = obj.Value
                      let result = obj.Expensive()
                      where val.StartsWith("a")                      
                      select result).ToArray();    
    }
}
```

The first query filters *then* projects (so it only does the expensive operation for the matching records), while the second query calculates the expensive operation for both:

```
query1:
abc
query2:
abc
def
```

It should be noted that `let` is actually just implemented via `Select` - it is a projection from the source data to an anonymous type used internally to the query.